# Can I ask any software related question? (Not programming related)

Tags: discussion, questions

Can we ask any question related to any software like Tectia, Eclipse or any other software which required for programming. But the question is not directly associated with any code or programming answer.

For example:

1. How to export/import Saved Profiles in Tectia?
2. What are the available shortcuts on Eclipse? Like: Convert to User Case any Selected Text

Comment: Not asking the question which are easily found in google like the above two question. But which I did not found If I ask such will it be allowed?

Comment: The second one, definitely not. The first one, yes, possibly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions about programming tools are not *automatically* off topic but they, too, need to conform to the site's general question standards.

> What are the available shortcuts on Eclipse?

This would immediately be closed as a "list question".

The first question might work better, but it appears that both questions can be very easily Googled.

Always remember to do a search first to see whether you can answer your question on your own. For many questions around programming tools, there already is a solution that can be easily found.

If an extensive search gives you no obvious answer about how to do something with your programming tool, it *may* be worth asking on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have also found this URL with a good description http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Huh? "List question"? Never heard of the term, what's that? There exists no such close reason. According to SO Help, asking questions about Eclipse is perfectly fine since it is a software tool used by programmers.

Comment: Also, "just Google it" is explicitly listed as an invalid close reason nowadays. The "user must show minimal effort" close reason has been removed and is no longer a valid close reason.

Comment: @Lundin "List questions" are usually "too broad" which is off-topic.  (They might also be off-site recommendation or primarily opinion based.)

Comment: @ryanyuyu Then it is a "too broad" question. Just because a question asks for a list of something, it isn't necessarily off topic. For example, suppose someone asks for a list of all valid keywords in a given programming language, [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319550/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-reserved-keywords-in-c). I think such a question is pretty good, definitely not off-topic.

Comment: @Lundin that isn't a list question, it's a "find me documentation" question.

Comment: I was just about to say, that's very off-topic. Its the answer that is good, not the question.

Comment: @KevinB Then I'm curious: what questions on SO do you think there are, for which there exists no written documentation or programming books? We should close the whole of SO then, because it is 99% "find me documentation" questions.

Comment: @Lundin There's a big difference between "Where do i find information on X" and "How do i do X". Generally what they really meant to ask though is How do i do X, which is far more likely to be on topic.

Answer (score 1):

Asking questions about (to quote SO help) "software tools commonly used by programmers" is perfectly fine and on-topic. For example, questions about compilers, programming IDEs, version control, debuggers, linkers, scripts etc.

What you should be aware of are questions like:

- "I'm having trouble booting my programming PC..."
- "I'm writing programs for board x, how to solve this hardware issue the board."
- "I'm writing a program to solve the mathematical equation x, how can I formally prove x?"

That is, claiming that something is related to programming as an excuse to drop a question which is off-topic. (The above examples should have been asked on other sites: Super user, Electrical engineering and Mathematics)